GL Impact added to workflow email
I have been trying like crazy to hunt down a way to add the GL impact to my workflow that sends an email everytime an assembly is built.Is there a way to get GL impact in the body of the email of my workflow? From what I have gathered there is a script that needs made and deployed just need more guidance. Any help is greatly appreciated!
I have tried numerous combinations of different AI engines and just can't work my way through it. I also deep dived into suite answers and already asked the question on Oracle community. I have to workflow working well and just want to add the GL impact from the assemblies as they are being built

The most direct way to do this almost doesn't need a workflow but you can create a workflow action script that uses N/search to pull the GL Impact N/render with a custom template to lay it out and N/email to send the email.
There may be a way to save the rendered search into a Long Text workflow state variable and use the natural workflow email action but that seems pointless given the other work you'll need to do.
All of the above could likely be done as a User Event After Submit script and, IMO, is cleaner unless you want to have some logic involved in triggering the email that you'd like to make easier for an admin to adjust.

I am very novice user when it comes to scripting. The only trigger I need is when an Assyb# is created an email goes out. I've been told it can be done with a saved search even just don't know my way around enough yet to get where I need to be

You might want to contact a NetSuite professional to help you out then.
